# Complete Imbreeding.Holder Spaces. Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

I would need some help in prove some properties of Holder Spaces. 
I should prove that $C^{1,\alpha}(X) \subseteq \subseteq C^{0,\beta}(X)$ for $\alpha,\beta\in (0,1), X=[a,b]$.
I can prove the fact that $C^{1,\alpha} \subseteq \subseteq  C^1$ but there is left to prove that $C^1  \subseteq  C^{0,\beta}$. So that differentiable funtions are Holder continuous. Any ideas?

Comment: $d \mapsto d^{1-\beta}$ is bounded on …

Comment: Is it just that we take some $u\in X$
Then we have for some $c \in [a,b]$: $|u(x)-u(y)|=|u'(c)||x-y| \leq M|x-y|^{\beta} |x-y|^{1-\beta} \leq M|a-b|^{1-\beta} |x-y| \leq K|x-y|^{\beta}$ ?

Comment: You need to express $K$ using the $C^1$-norm, but yes, it's just that.